# How can I get ‘n’ to go forward even if I started searching with ‘?’ or ‘#’?

Tags: cursor-movement, key-bindings, search

Vim has (at least) two sets of commands that search in opposite directions. Typing `/` and then a pattern will search forward through the document for the pattern; typing `?` and then a pattern will search backward. The same relationship exists between the `*` and `#` commands.

What I don’t like is that these commands also set the search direction for the `n` and `N` commands. After using `/`, `n` goes forward through the document and `N` goes backward; after using `?`, `n` goes backward and `N` goes forward. (In other words, `n` always goes in the same direction as the original search and `N` always goes in the other direction.)

How can I get `n` to go forward through the document, and `N` to go backward, regardless of which direction I started searching in?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can change the behaviour of `n` and `N` to search consistently downwards/upwards by useing the following:

```
nnoremap <expr> n 'Nn'[v:searchforward]
nnoremap <expr> N 'nN'[v:searchforward]
```

**Update:** How does it work?

This uses expression-maps, which maps the lhs of the map to an expression that will be evaluated, everytime the lhs is encountered. See `:h map-expression` in the help.

What happens is, that the v:searchforward variable (which determines the internal state of which direction the last search was, see `:h v:searchforward`) is used as an index for the string in front of it. So in case of the first map, if the last search direction was forward, the n will be mapped to 'n' (index of 1, meaning return the second character) and if it was backward, the 'n' will be mapped to 'N' (because the v:searchforward variable is 0 and therefore the 'N' will be returned.

An alternative way to write those maps would be (which might be clearer):

```
nnoremap <expr> n (v:searchforward ? 'n' : 'N')
nnoremap <expr> N (v:searchforward ? 'N' : 'n')
```

There are also some plugins, that do that (ie the [SearchRepeat plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4949) and possibly others as well).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my plugin; I was just about to recommend that as an alternative :-)

Comment: Clever use of subscripting!

Comment: Could you please add an explanation?  I haven't seen this syntax before, and I would like to know how it works.

Comment: @EvergreenTree The Vim variable 'v:searchforward' is 0 after a reverse search (e.g. '?') and 1 after a forward search (e.g. '/'). That is then used as the index to pick which letter ('n' or 'N') to use for the search. So, 'n' is mapped to 'N' if the search was reversed, but 'n' is mapped to 'n' for forward (e.g. it is left alone). The result is that 'n' will always search forward. The opposite is done for 'N'.

Comment: @EvergreenTree: Added some more explanation

Comment: @IngoKarkat: I remembered your plugin from a similar question, so I mentioned it ;)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt That is very clever.  I never thought of you using `v:searchforward` as an index.

Comment: indeed clever. And really slick.I Iike the idea and tried it for a while. Yet I have to stop using it since with this mapping vim no longer obeys the `foldopen` option. Anyway an upvote since most people will not be hurt by this flaw.

Comment: @Naumann correct, mappings do not respect the `foldopen` setting.  but to have it open folded lines, you could add the `zv` command to the mapping.

Comment: You should also use the corresponding `vnoremap` commands, so that visual mode search also has the n/N direction fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Christian Brabandt's solution I came up with

```
nnoremap <expr> n 'Nn'[v:searchforward].(&fdo=~'search\\|all'?'zv':'')
nnoremap <expr> N 'nN'[v:searchforward].(&fdo=~'search\\|all'?'zv':'')
```

These mappings also obey the `foldopen` setting

Answer (score 1):

I’m using the [SearchIndex](https://github.com/google/vim-searchindex) plugin. To use Christian Brabandt’s answer but keep the plugin’s functionality of displaying the match number each time I type <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd>, I put this in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <silent><expr> n (v:searchforward ? 'n' : 'N') . ":SearchIndex<CR>"
nnoremap <silent><expr> N (v:searchforward ? 'N' : 'n') . ":SearchIndex<CR>"
```