# Set highlighted token to blink during search and replace

Tags: search, highlight

When I do a global search and replace with confirm (e.g.,
`:s/t/s/gc`) I have a lot of trouble seeing which of many occurrences is currently under the cursor.

I've tried the usual tricks, e.g., `hi IncSearch ctermfg=Black  ctermbg=lightyellow cterm=bold,underline,reverse` but still have trouble.

I think it would help some if I could make the cursor blink aggressively in addition to the other settings.

I've read [this posting](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/interrupting-blink-highlighting-function-if-mapping-is-invoked-again) and tried to understand [this video](https://youtu.be/aHm36-na4-4) but they are way too complicated for me. Is there any way to get a blink simply by adding another attribute to `cterm`?

Thanks very much for any suggestions!

Comment: Well if an experimented Vimmer like Damian Conway created a function to make the highlighting blink it is not because it is fun it is because there's no way to do it simply with `cterm`. The highlighting commands defines how text should look like but they don't have an option to create blink. Now what is your exact problem with the links you gave? Why are they to complicated? You have trouble using them? If so what is your trouble?

Comment: What you're asking for is exactly what is provided by Damian Conway's [Vimscript](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2770/343). You don't have to understand it. You just have to copy it into your .vimrc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set cursor colour different when on a highlighted word](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/set-cursor-colour-different-when-on-a-highlighted-word)

Comment: This is about `:s///c` not `n`, though you could use `gn` and replace interactively that way, but then you're not getting the benefit of the `:g`.

Comment: Sorry statox, I should have elaborated.      As Antony noted,  Conway's script doesn't work with global substitutions.   In fact I can't get it to work with `n` either, because I can't find an example of usage.    I also can't figure out how to experiment with  @DevSolar's adaption of Conway's script, which addresses exactly the problem I have, but again, not for global substitutions with confirmation.  So, specifically, my trouble is that I don't know how to adapt @DevSolar's script for commands of the form `g/t/s//c/gc`

Comment: @Antony You're right, and I apologise to Leo for not reading his question properly.