# Can I use a different color for the selected match than for other matches

Tags: search, highlight

In the screencast below I searched `statusline` and then cycle through the results with `n`.

**Is it possible to highlight the selected match with a different color than the other matches**, instead of having them all highlighted in yellow and relying only on the user to notice that the very first character of the match has the usual background color (purple in my case) instead of yellow?

[image]

Comment: I don't think, that this is possible, but would be nice.

Comment: @Ralf Since you seemed interested, check out my solution

Comment: In addition to the great answers here, see also the alternative ones here: [Set cursor colour different when on a highlighted word](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/set-cursor-colour-different-when-on-a-highlighted-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, based on the answer of B Layer and those of many other stackexchange heroes.

It supports incremental search highlighting as well and keeps the highlight color of the incremental search highlight after pressing Enter and after pressing `n` and `N`.

[image]

This is the responsible code. (It includes changing the statusline color according to whether there are any matches at all or not. For example, you can see it switch to red when I type `statuslim` accidentally. Not included is the code that highlights the linenumber column in red and 
the fact that I am using the plugin `romainl/vim-cool` to remove search highlights when the cursor isn't on a match)

```
function! HighlightSearch(timer)
    if (g:firstCall)
        let g:originalStatusLineHLGroup = execute("hi StatusLine")
        let g:firstCall = 0
    endif
    if (exists("g:searching") && g:searching)
        let searchString = getcmdline()
        if searchString == "" 
            let searchString = "."
        endif
        let newBG = search(searchString) != 0 ? "green" : "red"
        if searchString == "."
            set whichwrap+=h
            normal h
            set whichwrap-=h
        endif
        execute("hi StatusLine ctermfg=" . newBG)
        let g:highlightTimer = timer_start(50, 'HighlightSearch')
        let g:searchString = searchString
    else
        let originalBG = matchstr(g:originalStatusLineHLGroup, 'ctermfg=\zs[^ ]\+')
        execute("hi StatusLine ctermfg=" . originalBG)
        if exists("g:highlightTimer")
            call timer_stop(g:highlightTimer)
            call HighlightCursorMatch()
        endif
    endif
endfunction
function! HighlightCursorMatch() 
    try
        let l:patt = '\%#'
        if &ic | let l:patt = '\c' . l:patt | endif
        exec 'match IncSearch /' . l:patt . g:searchString . '/'
    endtry
endfunction
nnoremap n n:call HighlightCursorMatch()<CR>
nnoremap N N:call HighlightCursorMatch()<CR>
augroup betterSeachHighlighting
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdlineEnter * if (index(['?', '/'], getcmdtype()) >= 0) | let g:searching = 1 | let g:firstCall = 1 | call timer_start(1, 'HighlightSearch') | endif
    autocmd CmdlineLeave * let g:searching = 0
augroup END
```

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** *For those in a hurry, not interested in the process/context, etc...jump to the last two code blocks, `augroup procsearch` and `function ProcSearch`. Copy those to your vimrc for a complete solution that works seamlessly with native search (as demonstrated in the GIF).*

Haven't considered this before but I think I have the seed of a solution...

If you run this command after you've started the search then the match that the cursor is on should be highlighted differently (I've tested that this is so while cycling through matches with `n`/`N`)...

```
:exec 'match HI /\%#' . @/ . '/'
```

The key is `\%#` which is pattern representing cursor position. (Note: if you enable `'ignorecase'` I think you'll need to add `\c` to the beginning of this pattern.)

Replace `HI` with whatever highlight group you prefer. (For testing with something highly visible you can try `Error`.)

Disable the behavior with

```
:match none
```

Obviously you don't want to type that all in whenever you need it. The easiest thing to do is map it. Something like

```
:nnoremap <leader>n  exec 'match HI /\%#' . @/ . '/'<CR>
```

---

Okay so we've established that you want this behavior every time you do a search. We need to overload the search operation so that the match command is invoked immediately after the usual business.

...

*I removed my previous attempts at a solution since I've got a much better approach and this thing had gotten too long. Feel free to look at the history...if you're so inclined.* ;)

...

Though I earlier bemoaned the lack of an autocommand event for search turns out there is such a thing it's just more general: `CmdLineEnter`/`CmdLineLeave`. And there is a way, once those events trigger, to distinguish between `:` commands and search commands (`/` or `?`) using special string `<afile>`.

So now all we need is an autocommand that will call a function each time a search command is completed:

```
augroup procsearch
  autocmd!
  au CmdLineLeave * let b:cmdtype = expand('<afile>') | if (b:cmdtype == '/' || b:cmdtype == '?') | call timer_start(200, 'ProcessSearch') | endif
augroup END
```

I did the call asynchronously (`timer_start()`) because otherwise the `/` register wasn't set yet.

Here's the callback that calls the `:match` command per usual, including proper `'ignorecase'` handling:

```
function! ProcessSearch(timerid)
    let l:patt = '\%#' . @/
    if &ic | let l:patt = '\c' . l:patt | endif
    exe 'match SpellRare /' . l:patt . '/'
endfunc
```

And you can unmap `<leader>/`...we don't need it anymore.

I don't always use the functional enhancements that I post as answers in my own config but this is useful enough that I believe I will. :)

[image: demo video]

*Note: next steps would be to make this a little more robust. For instance, the event is triggered even when user aborts out of search with, e.g. `Ctrl-C`, so we should check for that. Also, using a delay before calling the function is a little sketchy so that could be tightened up a bit. I'll probably leave these to readers...StackExchange is not about posting production-ready code it's about providing specific answers to specific question, IMO.*

Comment: Thanks, that's looks awesome succinct, I'll try it out tomorrow. I would indeed like this after each search and after each n. I thought I'd just remap "/" and "n" to first do their normal job and then run your command?

Comment: The current command maintains the highlighting through every `n` and `N`. The command only needs to be run once after the initial search. But then, yes, somehow `/` needs to be overloaded with search and my command. I don't know that it's as easy as it sounds. I'll try to work something out by the time you check it tomorrow.

Comment: Too bad there arent any autocmd events for searches...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ha, yes, I checked help to make sure I hadn't forgot about the existence of such events.

Comment: @BLayer you might be interested in the solution that I just posted. It's piecemeal from previous stackexchange questions but I think it pieces together quite nicely.

Comment: @Bananach Ha. I just came here to update mine with a much better approach than I was using ...and I see your addition. It seems mine is based on the same thing you uncovered: `CmdLine[Enter|Leave]`. Cool. :)

Comment: I think the autocmd pattern could be [/?] and then you can remove the if

Comment: Really? I'll try it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a plugin for this: [vim-current-search-match](https://github.com/airblade/vim-current-search-match).

Comment: Nice one as always! Is there a particular reason why you'd choose to default to `PMenuSel` rather than `IncSearch` (which is the default while typing a search)?

Comment: Thanks!  No strong reason; in the colorscheme I like to use, `IncSearch` is the same as `Search`.  Also I thought `PMenuSel` was sort-of appropriate, representing the selected option among several.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a vim plugin for this: https://github.com/borisbrodski/vim-highlight-hero

Highlight current word using default color, color1, color2, ...

- `:HH`
- `:1HH`
- `:2HH`

Highlight "string" using default color, color1, color2, ...

- `:HH string`
- `:1HH string`
- `:2HH string`

Help:

- `:help highlight-hero`

Bonus: Turn on auto-highlighing! (Navigate around to see the impact):

- `:HHauto`