# How can I change the syntax highlighting for currently highlighted search item?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme

When I search for something with `/` I get a series of finds, and as I press `n` for next, it highlights the next one. I always think I'm on the wrong one. Maybe my eyes see green and red, and they think I'm on green. I don't know, but I have to adjust those two colors.

How do I do that? Code is also in the screenshot below...

[image]

I can only edit the green background by changing `Search` but I can't seem to change the red background which signifies the item I'm currently on.

Comment: Is this after you press `enter`? Are you using any plugin (beside your colorscheme) which could change highlights?

Comment: Yes, after I press enter.

Comment: Yes I am : ( searchant.

Comment: Without the plugin, my search results stay highlighted forever. 'Esc' doesn't remove them.

Comment: I don't know about searchant, but it could be a nice plugin to have. Use :nohl if you want to clear your highlights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a different color for the selected match than for other matches](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18546/can-i-use-a-different-color-for-the-selected-match-than-for-other-matches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current search colour is set by the `IncSearch` highlight group.
That's the colour you'll see, *while* typing your search, on the current item (by the way, you can use `<c-t>` and `<c-g>` while typing to select previous / next item).

But once you hit `enter`, vim should display only one colour (from the `search` group), so I guess you are using a plugin to display a different colour for the current item.

## EDIT

That was driving me crazy. I wrote a function that highlights the match in a different colour.
Well, it's probably not the way to go, since a mapping is needed on `n` and `N` (and anything that starts a search, really), and it keeps the 'search hit bottom' from disappearing until the screen is moved.

Besides this caveat, it works quite fine.

```
function! HLCurrentMatch() abort
    call matchadd('IncSearch', '\c\%#'.@/, 101)
    redraw
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> n n:call HLCurrent()<cr>
nnoremap <silent> N N:call HLCurrent()<cr>
```

My vimscript skills are poor, but here's the main things to make it more viable in my opinion:

- Check if we're back to the first match, in order to, say, use a different match, which would even be better than the 'back to first match' message
- Enable it right when a new match is defined (with `/`, `*`, `#`...)

## FINAL

Here it is. This will use different highlight groups for the current match and for the edge matches.
Courtesy to @Zorzi for his help on [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25033/22375)

```
function! HLCurrent() abort
    if exists("currmatch")
        call matchdelete(currmatch)
    endif
    " match only on cursor
    let patt = '\c\%#'.@/
    " check prev and next match
    let prevmatch = search(@/, 'bWn')
    let nextmatch = search(@/, 'Wn')
    " if on first or last match
    if prevmatch == 0 || nextmatch == 0
        let currmatch = matchadd('EdgeSearch', patt, 101)
    else
        let currmatch = matchadd('IncSearch', patt, 101)
    endif
    redraw
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> n n:call HLCurrent()<cr>
nnoremap <silent> N N:call HLCurrent()<cr>
```

You'll need to define a "EdgeSearch" highlight group, for example:

```
highlight EdgeSearch guibg=green ctermbg=black
```

As for the "search hit bottom" message, it's not needed any more. It can be disabled with `set shortmess+=s`.

The code I use may change over time and can be found [here](https://github.com/Biggybi/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/plugin/search.vim).

Comment: Er, i *think* (i have to go check!) that with hlsearch on there are multiple colors (one for the active and one for all the others)

Comment: Okay, so removed the plugin. Things seem to work fine now, but... is there a way to affect the look of my current selection?

Comment: As I mentioned, and this is unfortunate, IncSearch does not seem to have any effect once the pattern is validated - but I may be doing something wrong.