# get line of first occurence of pattern in buffer

Tags: search

I am trying to write a function which I bind to "n" and "N" to highlight the current search pattern. That part works.

I would like to detect when the cursor wraps to the first match in the buffer (when 'search hit BOTTOM' is shown), and use a different highlight then.

But I fail getting the line where the search pattern first appears.

I know hot to get a list of lines with a global and `p` flag but am not sure if and how I should trim it.

```
g/pattern/p
```

I can also use `search()` with `n` flag (not to move the cursor), but I am only able to get the previous match with it.

So I tried to hack my way around the problem by setting the cursor position to the top of the file, then using `search()` to get the first line including the pattern, then restoring the cursor position. It seems to get the next search despite moving the cursor.

That's what it looks like:

```
function! HLCurrent() abort
    if exists("currmatch")
        call matchdelete(currmatch)
    endif

    let patt = '\c\%#'.@/                                  "set pattern
    let currline = line('.')                               "save current line
    let currcol = col('.')                                 "save current column
    call cursor(1, 1)                                      "move to top of file
    let firstmatchline = search(patt)                      "get first line with pattern
    call cursor(currline, currcol)                         "restore cursor


    if firstmatchline == getline('.')                      "always true
        let currmatch = matchadd('Todo', match, 101)
    else                                                   "never in else
        let currmatch = matchadd('IncSearch', match, 101)
    endif
    redraw
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> n n:call HLCurrent()<cr>
nnoremap <silent> N N:call HLCurrent()<cr>
```

### TL;DR

So the question is, how can I get the line of the first occurrence of a pattern properly?

Comment: Rather than trying to find the first match in the file, how about just checking whether the cursor moves up or down (by checking `line()` before and after? If the cursor moves up then you’ve wrapped around.

Comment: You should give a look to the `W` flag of `search`, it allows you to forbid the wrap around

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I guess both could do the trick, but I chose @Zorzi's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view, the easiest way to know if your cursor is at the first occurrence of the word is to search backwards with the `W` flag:

> ```
>   {flags} is a String, which can contain these character flags:
>
>                       [...]
>
>   'W'     don't Wrap around the end of the file
> ```

If there is no match found, then it's the 1st one:

```
function! HLCurrent() abort
    if exists("currmatch")
        call matchdelete(currmatch)
    endif

    let prevOccurence = search(@/, 'bWn')

    if prevOccurence == 0
        " First occurence
        let currmatch = matchadd('Todo', match, 101)
    else
        " Not first occurence
        let currmatch = matchadd('IncSearch', match, 101)
    endif

    redraw
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> n n:call HLCurrent()<cr>
nnoremap <silent> N N:call HLCurrent()<cr>
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you!