# Is it possible to detect a highlighted search match with synIDattr() or similar?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, search, highlight

When I have `hlsearch` on and my cursor is somewhere in a highlighted search match, is it possible to detect the search highlight `hl-Search` with `synIDattr()` or a similar function?

As far as I can tell by running the following command, it doesn't seem to be:

```
:echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
```

But perhaps that makes sense as a search highlight isn't a language syntax item.

In fact I can't find any way to get a list of the current search highlight positions, which surprises me.  Is this possible?

I found a number of similar questions to this but nothing that answered my question.

---

Motivation: my cursor is hard to see when it's on a highlighted match so I would like to change the cursor's highlight when it's on a match (and restore it when it's not).  To do this I need to detect when the cursor's on a search match.

An alternative approach might be to see if the last pattern (`@/`) is found at/around the cursor's position.

Update: here's a small function to do that:

```
function! CursorInSearchMatch(...)
  if !&hlsearch || !v:hlsearch | return 0 | endif
  let [match,start,stop] = matchstrpos(getline('.'), @/, (a:0 ? a:1 : 0))
  if empty(match) | return 0 | endif
  let col = getcurpos()[2]
  if col <= start | return 0 | endif
  if col <= stop  | return 1 | endif
  return CursorInSearchMatch(stop)
endfunction
```

I call it from `CursorMoved`.

Comment: try `:help searchcount()`?

Comment: I cover detection of search match instance containing the cursor here [Can I use a different color for the selected match than for other matches](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18551/11054) ... it changes the match's highlighting rather than the cursor's but it might help (if I'm reading your need correctly). It's based on `:h /\%#` which is worth reading.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I didn't know about `searchcount()` –  I can see it's fairly recent.  `searchcount().exact_match` seems to detect when the cursor is in a match.  Thanks!

Comment: @BLayer Thanks for that, I hadn't seen that answer and I had forgotten about `/\%#`.  After I posted my question I wrote a small function (see my updated question) using `matchstrpos()` which detects when the cursor is anywhere in the search match, not just at the start.

Comment: @AndyStewart if youve managed to answer your question, post it as answer please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a way to detect search highlighting.  A character's search highlight seems to be invisible to vimscript.

Having said that, you can detect when the cursor is in a search match by other means.

- `searchcount().exact_match` returns `1` if the cursor is in a search match.  Thanks @D.BenKnoble.
- `/\%#@/` can be used to determine whether the cursor is at the start of a search match.  Thanks @BLayer.
- The function I added to my question can be used if `searchcount()` isn't available.

Now I can tell when the cursor is in a search match, I can use `matchaddpos()` to highlight the "current" match on `CursorMoved`.  Here's my plugin [vim-current-search-match](https://github.com/airblade/vim-current-search-match).