# Key n moves up in the file instead of down

Tags: search

Sometimes `n` (next instance of a search) starts moving me up in the file instead of down. Could this be caused by a bug in a plugin?

Comment: What does `verbose map n` report?

Comment: `verbose map n` said no mapping found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'n' by default moves in the same direction as the last normal mode search command. So if you used `?` to search backwards, `n` will also search backwards. Until you use `/` again to search forward, in which case `n` will then again also move forward again. The same is true for `N`.

Here is a mapping that I use to have `n` always search forwards and `N` always continue searching backwards:

```
nnoremap <expr> n (v:searchforward ? 'n' : 'N')
nnoremap <expr> N (v:searchforward ? 'N' : 'n')
```

See also [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2366/71) answer where I explain that in more detail and also how those maps work.